# Gatsby plugin to add params to all outbound links in mdx?

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin-mdx

I’d like to automatically modify all outbound links in the .mdx. If the url matches a particular pattern, add a url param.

given `pattern=mycompany.com`

`[Company Page](https://mycompany.com/path)`
should become
`[Company Page](https://mycompany.com/path?trackingId=xxxxxx)`

or direct JSX

```
<a href=“https://mycompany.com/path2?param=something&trackingId=xxxxxx” />
```

Could this be a plugin that only modifies all urls upon build, like prefixPath (?)

Comment: Why don't customize directly the MDX link? Can you share how are you printing the article?

Comment: What I want to do is basically creating mdx with “plain” outbound links, and upon build-time automatically add some tracking code as url params. I may even reuse the exact same mdx in another project, which should use a different tracking code.